# Slim Twig request_method

Tags: php, twig, slim

How does one request a method within twig framework. As for php, it goes something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

And I need to request that same method with twig

Comment: you want to get data from post variables?

Comment: I want it to check if form is submitted. If so, change form action from one to other. So that if form is submitted, show new form

Comment: Twig framework? Twig is a template engine.

Comment: Sorry. I've made a mistake. I'm still learning stuff that's why I'm asking for information.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean within your route callable:

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/books', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        // form was posted back
    } else
        // GET only processing here
    }
    // processing for GET and POST here    
});
```

If you mean within the twig, then pass the `$request->getMethod()` to the render() call:

```
return $this->view->render($response, 'script.twig', [
    'method' => $request->getMethod()
]);
```

and you can use in Twig like this:

```
{% if method == 'POST' %}
    {# do something #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried every way i can think of to get it working with twig but it seems it does not displays nothing or gives me an error my get function $app->get('/pi/:id', function($id) use ($app) {

 $pI = $app->seT->where('id', $id)->first();
 
 if (!$pI) {
  $app->notFound();
 }
 
 $app->render( 'seT/pI.php', [
  'pI' => $pI  
 ]);

 
})->name('seT.item');